# Regex constants using $@ adding extra characters?

Tags: c#, regex

I'm constructing a regex string from a list of words using the following code snippet:

```
foreach (String w in ar)
        {
            c= $@"\b{w}\b|";  //**
            result = result + c;

        }
```

The first word in the array ar is "can".  When I inspect the value of c in the debugger after execution of the asterisked line, the debugger shows the following value.

```
"\\bcan\\b\b|"
```

I guess I sort of understand why the backslashes are doubled, but I don't understand why  the it contains an extra "\b" at the end before the vertical bar.

---

OK, I've tried the experiment suggested in the comments.
Putting in this code in the routine

```
            foreach (String w in ar)
        {
            System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine("w='" +w + "'");
            c= $@"\b{w}\b|";
            System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine("c='" + c + "'");
            result = result + c;

        }
```

I get this result in the console:

```
w='can'
c='\bcan\b|'
```

**However** the debugger is still showing the unusual string value in the watch expression.  Can somebody explain what that is?

[image]

Comment: I can't seem to reproduce the behaviour - maybe `w` also ends with `\b`?

Comment: How about you [edit] to add 1) what exactly is in `ar` at debug time (don't assume you know!) and 2) what `result` is after each iteration.

Comment: Yes, it would be simpler and more reproducible if you got rid of the loop and replaced the `foreach` with `var w = "can";` (or whatever `w` equals that's giving you the unexpected behavior), and replaced the `result` assignment with something like `Console.WriteLine(c);`. Then we can all play along! :)  (hint: when I do that on my machine, the output is `\bcan\b|`)

Comment: What IDE and version are you using? I had an odd quirk with arrays in VS Community 2015 that would replace the first value with 224 regardless of it's actual value (assuming it was numeric). Perhaps it's a similar bug?

Comment: Visual Studio for Mac Community 7.0.1 (build 24)

Comment: See if this helps, check "Enable the Visual Studio Hosting Process" under Project->Debug